# About generator and isomorphism problems for free groups operator algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.
The $C^{*}$-algebras and von Neumann here unital and subalgebras of $B(H)$.

**Definition** : Let $\mathcal{A}$ be $C^{*}$-algebra (resp. a von Neumann algebra),  $\mathfrak{gen}(\mathcal{A})$ is the fewest number of self-adjoint operators generating $\mathcal{A}$ as $C^{*}$-algebra (resp. as von Neumann algebra).

**Remark**:  If $\mathfrak{gen}(\mathcal{A}) \leq 2$ then $\mathcal{A}$ is called **singly-generated**, because if $x$ and $y$ are self-adjoint generators and $T = x+iy$, then $x = (T+T^{*})/2$ and $y = (T+T^{*})/2i$.

**Remark**: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra then  $\mathfrak{gen}(\mathcal{A''}) \leq  \mathfrak{gen}(\mathcal{A})$.

**Examples** :

- $\mathfrak{gen}(C([0,1]^{n}) = n$ and  $\mathfrak{gen}(L^{\infty}([0,1]^{n})) = 1$ (because $L^{\infty}([0,1]^{n}) \simeq  L^{\infty}([0,1])$)
- $\mathfrak{gen}(C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n})) \leq 2n$ because $\{a_{k}+a_{k}^{-1},i(a_{k}-a_{k}^{-1}) \vert k=1...n \}$ generates all.
- $\mathfrak{gen}(L(\mathbb{F}_{2})) = 2 $ (singly-generated):
  $L(\mathbb{F}_{2}) = W^{*}(a_{1},a_{2})$, however $W^{*}(a_{1})
     \simeq L^{\infty}([0,1]) = W^{*}(S)$ with $S$ self-adjoint. Then
  $\exists S_{1}, S_{2} \in B(H)$ self-adjoint, such that $W^{*}(a_{k})
     = W^{*}(S_{k})$. So $L(\mathbb{F}_{2}) = W^{*}(S_{1}+iS_{2})$.
- Idem: $\mathfrak{gen}(L(\mathbb{F}_{n})) \leq n $

In this [paper](http://mitizane.ll.chiba-u.jp/metadb/up/C0000050531/single.pdf) (example 5 page 4) Masaru Nagisa shows that the full group $C^{*}$-algebra $C^{*}(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ generated by the free group $\mathbb{F}_{2}$, is **not** singly generated.

> **Question 1** :  Is the problem of whether "$ C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n}) $ is singly generated" still open ?
> (Narutaka Ozawa : "yes")

**Generator problem for von Neumann algebras**  : Are
every von Neumann algebras singly generated ?
*Examples* (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511327.pdf)) : those hyperfinite, those with a Cartan subalgebra, $L(\mathbb{F}_{2})$.
*Still open* (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3879.pdf)) : the free group factor $L(\mathbb{F}_{n})$, $n>2$.

**Remark**: $L(\mathbb{F}_{n})=C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n})''$, so $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n})$ is (still) not known to be singly generated (**question 1**).

**Free group factor isomorphism problem**  : $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m})$, $\forall n, m \geq 2$ ?
**Remark** : Pimsner and Voiculescu showed ([here](http://www.theta.ro/jot.html) 1982, 8(1)) that $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \not\simeq C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{m}) $  by computing their $K$-theory : $ K_{1}(C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n}))  = \mathbb{Z}^{n}$.

> **Question 2** : Are there free interpolated $C^{*}$-algebras $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{s})$ ?  $\not\simeq$ ?   What about their $K$-theory ?
> (N. Ozawa: "I don't know") $\to$ (*see question 4*)

**Theorem** ([here](https://doi.org/10.2969/aspm/03810135) p 137) : Let $\mathcal{A}$ be $C^{*}$-algebra and $r = \mathfrak{gen}(\mathcal{A}) $ then :   $$\mathfrak{gen}(\mathcal{A} \otimes M_{n}(\mathbb{C})) \leq \lceil  1+(r-1)/n^{2} \rceil$$

> **Question 3** : Is it true for von Neumann algebras ?
> (N. Ozawa: "yes") $\to$ (*reference or proof ?*)

**Theorem** ([here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=A9C36B7AC7537F510D02C9A364E65E4D?doi=10.1.1.49.1853&rep=rep1&type=pdf) p 3): Free interpolated  $L(\mathbb{F}_{r}) \otimes M_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{1+(r-1)/n^{2}})$

**Remark** : See the correspondence with "$1+(r-1)/n^{2}$" for the two previous theorems.

**Corollary** : $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{(n-1)k^{2}+1}) \otimes M_{k}(\mathbb{C})$ (in particular $L(\mathbb{F}_{2}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{5}) \otimes M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$).

**Definition**: A $C^{*}$-algebra  $\mathcal{A}$  is "**connected**" if it does not contain nontrivial projections.
Note that the commutative $C^{*}$-algebra $ C(X)$  is "*connected*" iff $X$ is connected.

**Kadison-Kaplansky conjecture** : for every torsion-free discrete group $\Gamma$, $C^{*}_{r}(\Gamma)$ is "*connected*".

**Remark**: $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \not\simeq C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{(n-1)k^{2}+1}) \otimes M_{k}(\mathbb{C})$ because $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n}) $ is "*connected*".
Nevertheless, they are **von Neumann equivalent**.

> **Question 4** :
>
> - Is there a (**unique**) "*connected*" $C^{*}$-algebra,  *von Neumann equivalent* to the $C^{*}$-algebra $pM_{n}(C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{m})
>   )p$, with $p \in M_{n}(L(\mathbb{F}_{m}) )$ a projection ?
> - Is its isomorphism class  given by $s = (m-1)/r^{2}+1$ with $r=n \tau(p)$?
> - If so, we call it the **free interpolated** $C^{*}$-algebra $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{s}) $. **What's its $K$-theory ?**

> (*This question has been improved after N. Ozawa's comment*)

**Remark** :  $\mathfrak{gen}(C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n})) \leq 2n$ then
$\mathfrak{gen}(C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \otimes M_{m}(\mathbb{C})) \leq 2$, for $m \geq \sqrt{2n-1}$, and so $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \otimes M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is singly generated.

**Consequence** : $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \otimes M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is also singly generated.

If the **free group isomorphism problem** is true, then $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ is singly generated.

**Summary** : "$L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m})$"  $ \Rightarrow $ "$L(\mathbb{F}_{n})$ is singly generated", $\forall n, m \geq 2$
Is the converse known to be true ?

> **Question 5** : "$L(\mathbb{F}_{n})$ is singly generated"  $ \Rightarrow $ "$L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m})$"  , $\forall n, m \geq 2$ ?
> (This question has been improved after N. Ozawa's comment)

**Remark** (thanks to Jon Bannon comment below):
The paper [Generator of $II_{1}$ factor](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1953.pdf) of Dykema-Sinclair-Smith-White, focuses on the properties of the invariant $\mathcal{G}(N)$ introduced by Junhao Shen. In particular: if $\mathcal{G}(L(\mathbb{F}_{r}))>0$ for any particular $r>1$, then the free group factors are not isomorphic and are not singly generated for $r$ large enough.
So if $L(\mathbb{F}_{r})$ is singly generated $\forall r>1$, then $\mathcal{G}(L(\mathbb{F}_{r})) = 0$. Does this imply $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m})$ ?

Comment: Q1: Yes. Q2: I don't know. Q3: Yes. Q4: No. The reduced free group C*-algebra does not contain nontrivial projections. Q5: No. $LF_2$ is singly generated. Q3-5 are all well-known facts.

Comment: Thank you @NarutakaOZAWA. I'm thoughless, $L(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ is obviously singly generated because $L(\mathbb{F}_{2}) = W^{*}(a_{1},a_{2})$, however $W^{*}(a_{1}) \simeq L^{\infty}([0,1]) = W^{*}(S)$ with $S$ self-adjoint. Then $\exists S_{1}, S_{2} \in B(H)$ self-adjoint, such that $W^{*}(a_{k}) = W^{*}(S_{k})$. So $L(\mathbb{F}_{2}) = W^{*}(S_{1}+iS_{2})$ is singly generated...

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA : $L(\mathbb{F}_{3})$ is not so obviously singly generated (is it ?), so I can easily improve the issue and obtain more non-obvious questions, by replacing  $L(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ by $L(\mathbb{F}_{3})$ or even $L(\mathbb{F}_{n})$.

Comment: To the downvoters: it is customary and polite to *explain* your reasons for downvoting a question. Perhaps you might like to leave suggestions for how the question could be improved.

Comment: Thank you @MTS, I'm agree with you. I have just improved the issue. There are now more non-obvious questions.

Comment: Despite N. Ozawa's prompt reply, I tend to prefer posts which ask a focused question rather than a salvo of questions

Comment: Also, I feel that more reflection before posting such barrages - this is not the first such post from SP - would be both more productive and more considerate

Comment: @YemonChoi : (+1/2) I'm half agree with you. You're right about "more reflection" implies "more productive and more considerate". Now we must not confuse a lack of reflection with some little "thoughtlessness" : I took 7 hours of my time to write this post, and I cite 6 papers. It is **now** well improved...

Comment: Next one focused question is better, but in this case, would you prefer I open 5 issues ? All this questions are very closed and interrelated, so I have posted them into one issue.

Comment: @ Sébastien Palcoux: It would be productive to check out some of the work of Junhao Shen, as can be found in the later chapters of Sinclair and Smith's Finite von Neumann Algebras and MASAs, for example.

Comment: Thank you @JonBannon ! The paper [*Generator of $II_{1}$ factor*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1953.pdf) of Dykema-Sinclair-Smith-White, focuses on the properties of the invariant $\mathcal{G}(N)$ introduced by Junhao Shen. In particular: if $\mathcal{G}(L(\mathbb{F}_{r}))>0$ for any particular $r>1$, then the free group factors are not isomorphic and are not singly generated for $r$ large enough.

Comment: You're welcome, Sébastien Palcoux. Good luck!

Comment: I have highly improved the question 4 !